# Is there a difference between Ubuntu Gnome-shell and Fedora Gnome-shell?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, fedora

I am using ubuntu 11.10 with gnome-shell installed.   I often hear people talking about the "pure gnome-shell experience" with regards to Fedora.

What does this mean? Are there differences between the two?

Comment: They are one and the same exact sofware...

Comment: So is it simply the fact that gnome-shell is the default in fedora, unity for ubuntu?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fedora have packages that are much more recent than the offered in Ubuntu, that's why I prefer Fedora. The icons and fonts are Gnome ones, and the packages are much more integrated. But even Fedora doesn't come with Web (Gnome's default web browser, Epiphany Browser), it comes with Firefox. I prefer Web and always have to install it. Some say that Gnome plans to make a distro, that will sove that question, but i prefer the idea of having at install of Fedora, a option called something like "Pure Gnome", that gives the user only the full Gnome experience.

Answer (score 0):

both are same but i feel it's my personal perspective it may be wrong but the gnome shell in ubuntu is more beautiful than in fedora , The fonts look rather blurred overall, not helped by the low-contrast theme. Then, you also get icons that are rendered with low quality, making the product feel cheap. i love ubuntu and with gnome 3 shell it is the best one